# How to generate canvas element server side and send it to client in Node

Tags: node.js, html5-canvas

I want to create a canvas element server side, convert that into an image, then send it to the client. I want to perform this in Node.

I am facing a problem in creating a canvas element server side.

Answer (score 2):

node.js does not have any kind of DOM by default and can't operate on elements such as `canvas`. But you can look here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

That package allows you to manipulate a canvas-like object server-side.